# proper .htaccess settings to redirect home.html to main url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect my domain.com/home.html to just domain.com url, i've set some rules but it's redirecting me to domain.com/?url=home. Settings look like this:

```
RewriteRule /home.html http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Why it puts ?url=home at the end?

Comment: We need to see your other rules too.

Comment: the main rule is `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?url=$1 [L]` and also `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it's almost okay, i tried to put whole url before the $1 because it's redirecting me to the root folder, f.e. domain.com/var/www/clients/client3/web331/web/ but still no effect

Comment: okay, sorry, it's something about cache, now it's okay when i put whole address before.

Comment: @milan what if my home page is http://example.com/home and I want it to redirect to http://example.com ?

Comment: @angry_kiwi isn't it obvious you just have to remove the .html part?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your rules are in the right order. This one will need to come first to avoid being affected by subsequent writes...

```
RewriteRule /home.html http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```